# Which one is efficient to launch camera in android?

Tags: android, camera

I have an application with a button, when clicked it should launch camera. Developer guide mentions two ways to do it. But I am not able to decide which one is best suitable for me and what is the difference between them.
If possible please mention why android has two ways to work with cameras?

Comment: Can you please link to the 2 ways you're referring to?

Comment: do we look like we know android devs guide on top of our heads? XD

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html is the link.please see the sub heading "The Basics"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing intent will work for you.
Try this code in your onClicklistener.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

The default android camera has the ok and cancel button. So you don't have to worry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Android allows you to use Camera either passing a Intent or making a custom camera.

If you just need to perform a click and save feature you can use the Intent way.

Else if you need to put your custom features in the android using Custom Camera.

Hope this solves your purpose.

Comment: In my application I just need two buttons when camera launches, one is "OK" and another is "CANCEL". Can I do this with the help of camera intent or I have to use the Camera API?